# Are RPG tool support questions on topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

I'm keen to use RPGwithme.com and it seems to require a character import from HeroLab or similar.

Would questions on how to use tools like this be on-topic?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes.

We handle questions about the Wizards character builder and compendium and other online tools.

I'm not sure you'll get good answers here, but the questions should be on topic.